# Close accordion if clicked on the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have accordion on my website. It's working perfectly. If one accordion is open and clicks on second then it will close the previous one.  There is no issue till now.

My issue is, I have to close the accordion if clicked on the same. I mean if the accordion is open and clicks on the same then it should be close.

Can you check my script where should I add close script?
I tried  like

```
 $('.ac-pane.active .ac-title').click(function(){
 getparent.find('.ac-pane').removeClass('active');
 //  $(this).next('.ac-content').slideUp();
 $('.ac-pane .ac-content').css('display', 'none');

 });
```

```js
//Accordion
$(function() {
  'use strict';

  var selector = $('.ac-title');

  $('.accordion-wrapper').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.ac-pane').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.ac-pane.active .ac-content').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });

  selector.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // get the attr value
    var attr = selector.attr('data-accordion');
    var getparent = $(this).closest('.accordion-wrapper');

    if ($(this).attr('data-accordion') == 'true') {

      if ($(this).next('.ac-content').is(':visible')) {
        return false;
      } else {

        getparent.find('.ac-content').slideUp();
        $(this).next('.ac-content').slideDown();
        getparent.find('.ac-pane').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      }

    } else {
      $(this).next('.ac-content').slideToggle();
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.ac-pane {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #000;
}

.ac-pane:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ac-content {
  display: none;
}

.ac-title {
  /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
}

.ac-title i {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.ac-title i:before {
  content: "\f107";
}

.active .ac-title i:before {
  content: "\f106";
}

.ac-content {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="heading">
          <h2>Accordion Demo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-wrapper">
          <div class="ac-pane active">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ac-pane">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ac-pane">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ac-pane">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: follow this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: @AswinKumar, Thanks for the link but I am not using a bootstrap accordion.

Comment: You have to accept a valid answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar where you select the `parent` of clicked element and remove active class from siblings elements and also `slideToggle` clicked elements content.

```js
$('.ac-pane.active .ac-content').css('display', 'block');

$(".ac-title").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const parent = $(this).parent('.ac-pane');
  const siblings = parent.siblings('.ac-pane');
  
  siblings.removeClass('active');
  siblings.find('.ac-content').slideUp();
  
  parent.toggleClass('active');
  parent.find('.ac-content').slideToggle();
})
```

```css
.ac-pane {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #000;
}

.ac-pane:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ac-content {
  display: none;
}

.ac-title {
  /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
}

.ac-title i {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.ac-title i:before {
  content: "\f107";
}

.active .ac-title i:before {
  content: "\f106";
}

.ac-content {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="heading">
          <h2>Accordion Demo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-wrapper">
          <div class="ac-pane active">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ac-pane">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ac-pane">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ac-pane">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your answer is also working for me. Upvote from my side. Can you help me out in this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547013/how-to-hide-the-horizontal-scroll-bar-while-scrolling-in-mobile/56547079?noredirect=1#comment99677593_56547079

Answer (score 1):

if accordian is visible

```
$(this).next('.ac-content').slideUp();
$(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
```

**DEMO**

```js
//Accordion
$(function() {
  'use strict';

  var selector = $('.ac-title');

  $('.accordion-wrapper').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.ac-pane').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.ac-pane.active .ac-content').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });

  selector.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // get the attr value
    var attr = selector.attr('data-accordion');
    var getparent = $(this).closest('.accordion-wrapper');

    if ($(this).attr('data-accordion') == 'true') {

      if ($(this).next('.ac-content').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next('.ac-content').slideUp();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
      } else {

        getparent.find('.ac-content').slideUp();
        $(this).next('.ac-content').slideDown();
        getparent.find('.ac-pane').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      }

    } else {
      $(this).next('.ac-content').slideToggle();
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.ac-pane {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #000;
}

.ac-pane:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ac-content {
  display: none;
}

.ac-title {
  /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
}

.ac-title i {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.ac-title i:before {
  content: "\f107";
}

.active .ac-title i:before {
  content: "\f106";
}

.ac-content {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="heading">
          <h2>Accordion Demo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-wrapper">
          <div class="ac-pane active">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ac-pane">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ac-pane">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ac-pane">
            <a href="#" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
              <span>Hello World</span>
              <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ullam architecto earum reprehenderit dolore iusto labore sed, sunt, quasi soluta assumenda, a quam aspernatur repudiandae enim. Architecto, assumenda tempore vitae!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Let me check your answer.

Comment: @AswubKumar, Your answer is also working for me. Upvote from my side. Can you help me out in this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547013/how-to-hide-the-horizontal-scroll-bar-while-scrolling-in-mobile/56547079?noredirect=1#comment99677593_56547079